# Back up software that detects removable devices

Tags: windows, backup

Is there a software on Windows that detects removable devices and starts the backup of the connected device?

Comment: Any particular version of Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One such program is called [Allway Sync](https://allwaysync.com/), in which one creates a backup (synchronizing profile) and sets the parameters to recognize a specific detachable device. External hard drives and flash drives are supported, as are networked drives.

I've used this for clients with limited understanding of the systems. It allows them to insert the flash drive and specific folders are then copied (synchronized) to the device. Updated files are managed, existing files are ignored.

It's a free program for occasional, but extended use is noted and payment is then required. It's also not particularly expensive and can be useful.